# curl request and globbing bracket

Tags: curl, glob

I'm using Windows 10 and trying to ask docker based microservice with curl request, but there are some issues with 'globbing', adding `-globoff` does

```
curl -d '{"user":"X", "password":"Y", "settings": "[25,60,8,19,119,15,110,34,37,10,21,52,13,114,15,76,117,18,39,20,81]"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://127.0.0.1:25041
curl: (3) Port number ended with 'Y'
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: settings
curl: (3) [globbing] bad range in column 2
```

With `-globoff` :

```
curl -d -globoff  '{"user":"pgora", "password":"Ghzf8ftb", "settings": "[25,60,8,19,119,15,110,34,37,10,21,52,13,114,15,76,117,18,39,20,81]"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://127.0.0.1:25041
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched brace in column 2
curl: (3) Port number ended with 'G'
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: settings
curl: (3) [globbing] bad range in column 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `-globoff` **before** or **after** your post data `-d <data_string>` in the request.
Otherwise, `-globoff` is interpreted as a part of the post data.

```
curl -globoff \
 -d '{"user":"pgora", "password":"Ghzf8ftb", "settings": "[25,60,8,19,119,15,110,34,37,10,21,52,13,114,15,76,117,18,39,20,81]"}' \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 -X POST http://127.0.0.1:25041
```